# Take input from tkinter to python script and output from python script to tkinter

Tags: python, windows, user-interface, tkinter

I am facing an issue with my code I want my main code to take input from gui but it assumes returned zero , I don't know what is wrong I need help, also if there is a better way to apply gui to code please do not hesitate to mention it, if there is something that I can read to help me get better please mention it
ps: the two codes are in two different files

Main code:

```
def get_audio():
    # This fuction uses the microphone as an input to speech and recognises it using speech recognition library
    # and it tries to recognise the speech using google recogniser and if it didn't recognise it returns the exception
    # else it returns the speech as text
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Listening...")
        r.pause_threshold = 1
        audio = r.listen(source)
    try:
        text = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en')
        print('User: ' + text + '\n')

    except sr.UnknownValueError:


        speak('Sorry! I didn\'t get that! Try typing the command!')

        __import__(said)
        text=str(said)
```

tkinter code

```
stdoutQueue=queue.Queue()

def click():
    said=commandentry.get()
    print(said)
    return (said)

def producer(input):
    while True:
        line = input.readline()
        stdoutQueue.put(line)
        if not line:
            break
def consumer(output, root, term='<end>'):
    try:
        line =stdoutQueue.get(block=False)
    except queue.Empty:
        pass
    else:
        if not line:
            output.write(term)
            return
        output.write(line)
    root.after(250, lambda: consumer(output, root, term))
def redirectGui(command, root):
    input = os.popen(command, 'r')
    output =GuiOutput(root)
    thread.start_new_thread(producer, (input,))
    consumer(output, root)

if __name__=='__main__':
    window = Tk()
    window.geometry("484x670")
    window.title("Jarvis assistant")
    scroll = Scrollbar(window)
    scroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill='y')
    photo = PhotoImage(file="JARVIS background.PNG")
    Label(window, image=photo, bg='navy blue').pack(side=TOP, expand=True, fill=BOTH)
    Label(window, text="Type or say your command:", fg='black').pack(side=TOP)
    commandentry = Entry(window, width=60)
    commandentry.pack(side=TOP)
    Button(window, text="Send", width=8, command=click).pack(side=BOTTOM)
    redirectGui('python -u jarvis.py', window)
    window.mainloop()
```

How can I do it ?

main whole code

```
music = ["song", "music", "play song", "play music", "some music"]
weather = ["what is the weather in", "weather in", "current weather", "today's weather"]
forecast = ["weather forecaste", "forecast"]
jokes = ["What do you call a cow in an earthquake , . , . A milkshake",
         "What did the shark say when it ate a clown-fish . , . , this tastes funny",
         "what do you get when you put a vest on an alligator . , . , an investigator ",
         "How do you keep warm in a cold room  . , . , you go to a corner because its always 90 degrees",
         "I'm reading a book about anti-gravity. , . , I can't put it down.",
         "Time flies like an arrow. , . , Fruit flies like a banana.",
         "What do you call a nervous javelin thrower? , . , . Shakespeare."]
scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly']
Months = ["january", "february", "march", "april", "may", "june", "july", "august", "september", "october", "november",
          "december"]
Days = ["saturday", "sunday", "monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday"]
DayExtension = ["st", "nd", "rd", "th"]
CalenderWords = ["what do i have on....", "do i have plans", "am i busy", "plants", "events", "plans"]
Note_jarvis = ["make a note", "write this down", "remeber that"]


# make voice assisstant speak
def speak(text):
    engine = pyttsx3.init()
    engine.setProperty('rate', 125)
    engine.say(text)
    engine.runAndWait()




# get audio from user
def get_audio():
    # This fuction uses the microphone as an input to speech and recognises it using speech recognition library
    # and it tries to recognise the speech using google recogniser and if it didn't recognise it returns the exception
    # else it returns the speech as text
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Listening...")
        r.pause_threshold = 1
        audio = r.listen(source)
    try:
        text = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en')
        print('User: ' + text + '\n')

    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        speak('Sorry! I didn\'t get that! Try typing the command!')
        text=str(input('enter your command: '))

    return text




# greet user according to the time
def greetMe():
    currentH = int(datetime.datetime.now().hour)
    if currentH >= 0 and currentH < 12:
        speak('Good Morning!')

    if currentH >= 12 and currentH < 18:
        speak('Good Afternoon!')

    if currentH >= 18 and currentH != 0:
        speak('Good Evening!')


# OPEN NOTEPAD TO WRITE IN IT
def note(text):
    date = datetime.datetime.now()
    file_name = str(date).replace(":", "-") + "-note.txt"
    with open(file_name, "w") as f:
        f.write(text)
    subprocess.Popen(["notepad.exe", file_name])


# Authenticate google to begin searching events in user calender
def authenticate_google():
    """check user credintals in google and get them to log in to their google calender """
    creds = None
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no valid credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', scope)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=creds)

    return service


# function return time and date of the event
def get_events(day, service):
    date = datetime.datetime.combine(day, datetime.datetime.min.time())
    end_date = datetime.datetime.combine(day, datetime.datetime.max.time())
    utc = pytz.UTC
    date = date.astimezone(utc)
    end_date = end_date.astimezone(utc)
    # currently logged in user primary, iso format is shown format of date
    events_result = service.events().list(calendarId='primary', timeMin=date.isoformat(), timeMax=end_date.isoformat(),
                                          singleEvents=True,
                                          orderBy='startTime').execute()
    # List of events on the calendar
    events = events_result.get('items', [])

    if not events:
        speak('No upcoming events found.')
    else:
        speak(f"You have {len(events)} events on this day.")

        for event in events:
            start = event['start'].get('dateTime', event['start'].get('date'))
            speak(start, event['summary'])
            start_time = str(start.split("T")[0].split("-")[0])  # get the hour the event starts
            if int(start_time.split(":")[0]) < 12:  # if the event is in the morning
                start_time = (int(start_time) + 2) + "am"
            else:
                # int utc
                start_time = str(int(start_time.split(":")[0]) - 12)  # convert 24 hour time to regular
                start_time = start_time + "pm"
            speak(event["summary"] + " at " + "UTC" + (int(start_time) + 2))


def Date(text):
    text = text.lower()
    # To know where to start counting from
    today = datetime.date.today()
    # To check if text said contains today.
    if text.count("today") > 0:
        return today
    day = -1
    day_of_week = -1
    month = -1
    year = today.year

    for word in text.split():
        if word in Months:
            month = Months.index(word) + 1
        elif word in Days:
            day_of_week = Days.index(word)
        elif word.isdigit():
            day = int(word)
        else:
            for ext in DayExtension:
                found = word.find(ext)
                if found > 0:
                    try:
                        day = int(word[:found])
                    except:
                        pass
    # if month is before the month we are currently in , then the year will be next year (7amada helal reaction)
    if month < today.month and month != -1:
        year = year + 1

    # we have a day but not a month
    if month == -1 and day != -1:
        if day < today.day:
            month = today.month + 1
        else:
            month = today.month

        # if we only found a date of the week which is terrible to deal with e7na mmkn n7ot lluser specify ashl :)
    if month == -1 and day == -1 and day_of_week != -1:
        current_day_of_week = today.weekday()
        dif = day_of_week - current_day_of_week
        # if the day we are referring to is less than current day in index
        if dif < 0:
            dif += 7
            if text.count("next") >= 1:
                dif += 7
        # represent duration
        return today + datetime.timedelta(dif)
    # avoid error of returning a negative month which could cause an error :)
    if month == -1 or day == -1:
        return None
    return datetime.date(month=month, day=day, year=year)


Service = authenticate_google()
greetMe()

speak('Hello Sir, I am your voice assistant Jarvis ')
speak('How may i help you?')
print("Ready for you order")

if __name__ == '__main__':

    while True:

        text = get_audio()
        text = text.lower()
        for phrase in CalenderWords:
            if phrase in text:
                date = Date(text)
                if date:
                    get_events(date, Service)
                    speak("next command")
                    text = get_audio()
                    break
                else:
                    speak("Speak again ")

        # Tell weather in a city
        for word in weather:
            if word in text:
                speak("which city do you want?")
                city = get_audio()
                reg_ex = re.search(city, text.lower())
                if reg_ex:
                    city = reg_ex.group(1)
                    location = owm.weather_at_place(city)
                    condition = location.get_weather()
                    # target temperature conversion
                    temp = condition.get_temperature(unit='celsius')
                    for key, val in temp.items():
                        print(f'{key}={val}')
                        speak(f'{key}={val}')
                        speak("next command")
                        text = get_audio()
                        break

        # weather forecast
        for word in forecast:
            if word in text:
                reg_ex = re.search('weather forecast in (.*)', text.lower())
                if reg_ex:
                    city = reg_ex.group(1)
                    location = owm.weather_at_place(city)
                    weather = location.get_weather()

                    # temperature
                    temp = weather.get_temperature(unit='celsius')

                    for key, val in temp.items():
                        print(f'{key} => {val}')
                        break

                    # humidity, wind, rain, snow
                    humidity = weather.get_humidity()
                    wind = weather.get_wind()
                    rain = weather.get_rain()
                    snow = weather.get_snow()

                    print(f'humidity = {humidity}')
                    print(f'wind = {wind}')
                    print(f'rain = {rain}')
                    print(f'snow = {snow}')
                    speak(f'humidity = {humidity}' + "%")
                    speak(f'wind = {wind}')

                    # clouds and rain
                    loc = owm.three_hours_forecast(city)

                    clouds = str(loc.will_have_clouds())
                    rain = str(loc.will_have_rain())

                    if rain == True:
                        speak("It will rain")
                    else:
                        speak("no rain")
                    if clouds == True:
                        speak("It will be cloudy")
                        speak("next command")
                        text = get_audio()
                        break


                    else:
                        speak("It will not be cloudy today")
                        speak("next command")
                        text = get_audio()
                        break

        for words in music:
            if words in text:
                speak("name of the song")
                query_string = urllib.parse.urlencode({"search_query": get_audio()})
                html_content = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.youtube.com/results?" + query_string)
                search_results = re.findall(r'href=\"\/watch\?v=(.{11})', html_content.read().decode())
                webbrowser.open("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + search_results[0])
                speak("next command")
                text = get_audio()
                break

        else:
            if text in Note_jarvis:
                speak("what would you like me to write down sir")
                note_text = get_audio()
                note(note_text)
                speak("done sir")

            elif 'open youtube' in text:
                speak('okay')
                webbrowser.open('www.youtube.com')

            elif 'open google' in text:
                speak('okay')
                webbrowser.open('www.google.co.in')

            elif 'open gmail' in text:
                speak('okay')
                webbrowser.open('www.gmail.com')
            elif 'news' in text:
                webbrowser.open('https://www.bbc.com/news/world')
            elif "what\'s up" in text or 'how are you' in text:
                stMsgs = ['Just doing my thing!', 'I am fine!', 'Nice!', 'I am nice and full of energy']
                speak(random.choice(stMsgs))
            elif 'joke' in text:
                speak(random.choice(jokes))
            elif 'email' in text:
                speak('Who is the recipient? ')
                recipient = input("enter the email address: ")
                password = input('enter your password')
                speak("what is you google email address")
                # Allow less secure app in your google account to avoid being stuck in 4 hours of exception :)
                myemail = input("enter your email adress")
                try:
                    speak('What should I say? ')
                    content = ('Hello, \n Hope this email finds you well ' + get_audio())

                    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
                    server.ehlo()
                    server.starttls()
                    server.login(myemail, password)
                    server.sendmail(myemail, recipient, content)
                    server.close()
                    speak('Email sent!')

                except:
                    speak('Sorry Sir! I am unable to send your message at this moment!')



            elif 'nothing' in text or 'abort' in text or 'stop' in text:
                speak('okay')
                speak('Bye, have a nice day and do not forget to give my makers the full mark.')
                sys.exit()

            elif 'hello' in text:
                speak('Hello Sir')

            elif 'bye' in text:
                speak('Bye, have a nice day and do not forget to give my makers the full mark.')
                sys.exit()
            else:
                text = text
                speak('Searching...')
                try:
                    try:
                        res = client.query(text)
                        results = next(res.results).text
                        speak('Got it.')
                        speak('WOLFRAM-ALPHA says - ')
                        print(results)
                        speak(results)
                    except:
                        results = wikipedia.summary(text, sentences=2)
                        speak('Got it.')
                        speak('WIKIPEDIA says - ')
                        print(results)
                        speak(results)
                except:
                    # tld stands for domain because maybe we wamt to search in .com not scholar, pause is the time between each http request
                    query = text
                    for i in search(query, tld='com', lang='en', num=1, stop=1, pause=2.0):
                        print(i)
                        webbrowser.open(i)

            speak('Next Command! Sir!')
```

Comment: Is the indent right?

Comment: yes but It's my first time to copy into stack overflow so I probably didn't copy it right

Comment: I have revised your post, just check it.

Comment: ok , thanks they are two separate codes I want to link them together problem in main code is that it have too many function in it so I couldn't put gui directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For gui code I added another code named shared.py 
import tkinter as Tk
from tkinter import *

```
def on_click():
    said = commandentry.get()
    print(said)
    return said


window =Tk()
commandentry = Entry(window, width=60)
commandentry.pack(side=TOP)
Button(window, text="Send", width=8, command=lambda: on_click()).pack(side=BOTTOM)
window.mainloop()
```

for the main code to take only return value I used subprocess like this

```
cp = subprocess.run(['python.exe', 'shared.py'], universal_newlines=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                            stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        text= cp.stdout
```